# Compiler giving me an 'unreachable statment' error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is a method from my code and it's throwing me an 'unreachable statement' error when I attempt to compile it.

```
public static boolean whoareyou(String player)
{
    boolean playerwhat;
    if (player.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return playerwhat;
}
```

The exact error is:

```
java:82: error: unreachable statement
                return playerwhat;
                ^
```

I then attempt to use this boolean I return in the following code:

```
public static int questions(int diceroll, int[] scorep1)
{
 String wanttocont = " ";
 boolean playerwhat;
 for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
 {
   while (!wanttocont.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
   {
    wanttocont = input("Do you wish to continue?"); 
    // boolean playerwhat; wasn't sure to declare here or outside loop
    if (diceroll == 1)
    {
       String textinput = input("What's 9+10?");
       int ans1 = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
       output("That's certainly an interesting answer.");
       if (ans1 == 19)
       {
          if (playerwhat = true)
          {
             output("Fantastic answer player 1, that's correct!");
             diceroll = dicethrow(diceroll);
             scorep1[0] = scorep1[0] + diceroll;
             output("Move forward " + diceroll + " squares. You are on square " + scorep1[0]);
          }
          else if (playerwhat = false)
          {
             output("Fantastic answer player 2, that's correct!");
             diceroll = dicethrow(diceroll);
             scorep1[1] = scorep1[1] + diceroll;
             output("Move forward " + diceroll + " squares. You are on square " + scorep1[1]);
          }
    } // END if diceroll is 1
   } // END while wanttocont
 } // END for loop
} // END questions
```

I'm not sure if the above code is relevant to the question but I just wanted to show what I'm attempting to do with the boolean that is throwing me the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return playerwhat;` can never be reached, since either the `if` or `else` clause will return `true` or `false`. Therefore you should remove this statement. The `playerwhat` variable is not required.

BTW, your method can be replaced with a one liner method :

```
public static boolean whoareyou(String player)
{
    return player.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1");
}
```

I would rename this method to something more descriptive, such as `isFirstPlayer`.

EDIT :

You never call `whoareyou` is your `questions` method. You should call it :

Replace

```
if (playerwhat = true) // this is assigning true to that variable, not comparing it to true
```

with

```
if (whoareyou(whateverStringContainsTheCurrentPlayer)) {
    ..
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to remove the `return playerwhat;` at the end of the `whoareyou` method? If I do this then there isn't anything being passed to the `questions` method, as when I answer a question after having said I'm player 2 it still says `Fantastic answer player 1, that's correct!` when it should really say `player 2`.

Comment: @Overclock see edit. That's a different problem with your `questions` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tweaked what you said a little but it certainly worked wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your code this way

```
public static boolean whoareyou(String player)
{
    boolean playerwhat;
    if (player.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1"))
    {
        playerwhat = true;
    }
    else
    {
        playerwhat = false;
    }
    return playerwhat;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `if ("Player 1".equalsIgnoreCase(player))`

Comment: @SpringLearner agree we can have this too, but i just posted as per his original code

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static boolean whoareyou(String player)
{
    return player.equalsIgnoreCase("Player 1");
}
```

You have the issue, because:

> ```
> return player what;
> ```

is never reached. You exit the your function either through the "if"- or through the "else"-part.